# dtrace keep getting error "error on enabled probe...invalid user access in action #1"

Tags: dtrace

I am trying to use dtrace to calculate the fps of games in openGL and metal on the macOS. However, I keep getting an error saying:

```
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 2 (ID 86178: pid2741:OpenGL:CGLFlushDrawable:entry): invalid user access in action #1
```

when trying to get the fps of openGL games and I have no idea why.

Here is the script I have for the program I am executing:

```
#pragma D option switchrate=1000ms
#pragma D option bufsize=4m

BEGIN 
{ 
    i=timestamp; 
    diff=0; 
}
pid$1:OpenGL:CGLFlushDrawable:entry,
objc$1:CAMetalLayer:-nextDrawable:entry
{ 
    time = timestamp; 
    diff = time - i; 
    i = time;
    printf("%s,%s,%d",execname, probefunc, diff);

}
ERROR 
/pid==0/
{ 
    time = timestamp; 
    diff = time - i; 
    i = time;
    printf("%d\n",diff); 
}
```

I got the code above from the count it app's github page.

Comment: Looks like a ["System Integrity Protection"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) error designed to keep dTrace from telling you what's going on inside DRM'd apps such as iTunes.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275175/error-on-enabled-probe-syscallopen-nocancelentry-invalid-user-access-in-ac and https://superuser.com/questions/272029/what-does-this-dtrace-error-mean

Comment: I already have system integrity protection disabled though.